# Using Fork to Execute command in txt.file in C

Tags: c, linux, fork, execute

I want to create a c program that executes commands in a txt file. I read each value of my txt file and put them in an array and then I want to run them one by one using a fork function.
Thank you for your help

I hope a charitable help to tell me where the problem is.
I enclose a part of my code and my data file.

````
void Execfile(char*filename)
{
    char**T;
    int nb;
    FILE*f;
    char buff[MAX_ARG];
    f=fopen("data1.txt","rb");
     while(fgets(buff,MAX_ARG,f)!=NULL){
        T=File2TabArgv(filename,&nb);
    }
    fclose(f);
    execvp(T[0],T);
    printf("\n");
    printf("END");
}

in txt.file``` 
sleep20
````

Comment: ...is there a reason you're not using your shell to do this?

Comment: first of all, simply verify that you are cleanly read the data from the file into the array - ie print it out

Comment: So where is your attempt to use the `fork` function?

Comment: For each line read: create process with `fork()`, in child process close file, call `execvp()`; in parent process wait for child termination with `waitpid()`.

Comment: Instead of closing file every time in child process, since glibc 2.7 you can initially open it with "e" flag (O_CLOEXEC).

Comment: You can also explore `posix_spawn()` as an alternative to `fork()` and `exec()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`execvp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) *replaces the current process* (see the linked `man` page).  At minimum, you want to [`fork`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) into a new process, prior to calling `execvp`, and in the parent process, you will want to [`wait`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) for the newly forked child process.  You might want to do other things, like close the child's file handles inherited from the parent, and so on.

Without forking, the first "command" in your text file replaces you own execution.  Without waiting, you won't know what's going on.  This is sort of the basic flow of running executables from POSIX C.

Here is a pretty standard idiom for doing `fork`/`exec`, since it's helpful to see actual code:

```c
int do_fork_exec(void) {
    /* Just something to exec... */
    static char const exec_cmd[] = "ls";
    static char const *exec_args[] = { [0] = "-l", [1] = NULL, };

    pid_t const fork_result = fork();

    switch (fork_result) {
    case -1: {
        int const fork_errno = errno; /* Save it before it changes. */
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not fork a new process: %s\n",
                strerror(fork_errno));
        return fork_errno;
    }
    case 0: {
        printf("Child process executing: %s...\n", exec_cmd);
        int const exec_result = execvp(exec_cmd, (char **)exec_args);

        assert(exec_result == -1); /* Exec only returns on ERRORS. */
        int const exec_errno = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not excecute the process: %s\n",
                strerror(exec_errno));
        return exec_errno;
    }
    default: {
        printf("Forking process waiting for PID %d\n", fork_result);
        int child_result = -1;
        pid_t const wait_result = wait(&child_result);
        if (wait_result == -1) {
            int const fork_errno = errno; /* Save it before it changes. */
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not wait for PID %d: %s\n",
                    fork_result, strerror(fork_errno));
            return fork_errno;
        }
        /* Wait waits on the entire process group, and we only forked one
         * process, so I am asserting that what we forked is what we waited
         * for... */
        assert(fork_result == wait_result);
        printf("Child process with PID %d exited with a status of %d\n",
               fork_result, child_result);
        break;
    }
    }

    return 0; /* Return 0 on success. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a fork like this

```
int status;
my_pid = fork();
if (my_pid >= 0) {
   if (my_pid == 0) { /*child*/
      execvp(...);
      printf("failed\n");
      exit(1);
   } else { /*parent*/
      wait(&status);
      printf("child exit code: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
   }
} else {
   perror("fork failed");
   exit(1);
}
```